# Difference between memset() and initializinng array elements using a for loop?

Tags: c++

When I use `memset` inside the `printNGE` function I get the correct result also when I initialize the array elements to -1 in the `main()` , I get the correct result.

But when I initialize the same in the `printNGE` function using a for loop I get a wrong answer. It seems the initial value of the array elements in not changed inside the else part of the while loop for some reason? Please tell me what could be the possible reason for such discrepancies.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

/* arr[] of size n */

void printNGE(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    stack <int> s;
    int ans[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)//Set all the elements to -1
        ans[i] = -1;

    //memset(ans,-1,sizeof(ans));

    while (i<n)
    {
        if(s.empty() || arr[s.top()]>arr[i]) 
            s.push(i++);
        else
        {
            ans[s.top()]=arr[i];    
            s.pop(); //pop till incoming element is greater
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d -> %d\n",arr[i],ans[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]= {11, 13, 21, 3};
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    //int ans[n];
    //for(i=0;i<n;i++)//Set all the elements to -1
    // ans[i] = -1;
    printNGE(arr, n);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could find our by using a debugger and stepping through the code.

Comment: Additionally is -1 an exception. memset performs bytewise initialization of a data-block and a loop iterates over the elements. That means that other values than -1 (0xffffffff) would result in different states of the array.

Comment: To expand a bit on the comment by @h4x0r - this use of `memset` only works by accident. Try initializing the array to 2 instead of -1. Don't use `memset` here. In fact, in general, don't use `memset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index variable `i` of the `for` loop is not reset. Thus, the `while` loop won't get executed.

Comment: Just to murder the point. when you use `memset()` you're not incrementing `i` so the loop behaves as you expect.

Comment: Thanks purplepsycho!